# Use Google Sheets RIGHT formula in scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with a bunch of numbers in one column. How can I use google sheets `RIGHT` formula to take the last 4 numbers and paste them into the adjacent column? I am trying to write a function in Google Apps Script for this. There isn't much documentation on this so I am lost.

Comment: Why are you lost? did you try this for cell A1 for example: `right(A1,4)` ?

Comment: I need it in script form

Comment: What have you tried then ?

Comment: Nothing, I don't even know where to begin. There isn't any documentation on how to apply the LEFT or RIGHT function to Google sheets.

Comment: I posted my answer. For future reference, keep in mind that google apps script uses javascript, not google sheet formulas. If you want to look for a way to get the last 4 digits of a value. Then you need to look for javascript solutions because only those are supported in google apps script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

- One way to implement the `RIGHT` google sheets formula in google
  scripts is to get the desired value as a string and then use
  [slice(-4)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the last `4` digits of that number. Of course
  there are many ways to achieve the same goal but this is just one of
  them.
- To get the value of a cell as a string, you can use [getDisplayValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue). The following script will get the display value of cell `A1` and it will set the value of `B1` to the last 4 digits of cell `A1`.

### Code snippet:

Feel free to modify the sheet name (in my case `Sheet1`) and the input and output cells (in my case `A1` is the input and `B1` is the output).

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const value = sh.getRange('A1').getDisplayValue();
  const valueL4D = value.slice(-4);
  sh.getRange('B1').setValue(valueL4D);
}
```

**Input (A1) / Output (B1):**

[image]